# New to express, where do I start?

Tags: node.js, express

I’m learning node/express. I’ve purchased a few books and have followed some online guides and I would like to start tinkering around but I can’t figure out where to add logic to my routes.
I created a basic app using the express command line tool. I now have two routes defined in my app.js

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/users', user.list);
```

I see the jade templates and I think I am fully capable of serving plain old html through jade/stylus. But I want to add logic and I don’t see where to do that. Does it work like php, as in do I add the logic to the jade html files, or do I put it in the app.js somehow.

I saw in one example how to reference a variable in jade, but I would like to run code (server side, like php) when the page is displayed.

I’m referencing php a lot because it’s the only language I am familiar with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a common pattern is to separate logic into functions that you call from your routes, you can put these in separate files

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
require('http').createServer(app).listen(3000);
app.use(express.logger());
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(app.router);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/templates');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

var myLib = require('lib/myLib.js');
// myLib will contain: module.exports = { foo:function(req, arg, callback){ ... } };

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  myLib.foo(req, 'hello', function(err, result){
    // this is passed into foo as `callback` and generally is called from foo
    if(err){ return res.send(500) };
    res.send(200, 'Foo was ' + result);
  });
});

// edit - ways to structure this with app.render for a jade template
app.get('/jade1', function(req, res){
  myLib.bar(req, res); 
  // it is now myLib.bar's responsibility to send a response with the `res` object,
  // either with res.end, res.send, res.render, res.redirect or whatever
});

// my preferred way: (i usually try to keep my logic separated from req/res)
app.get('jade2', function(req, res){
  var username = req.body.username;
  myLib.getUser(username, function(err, result){
    if(err){ return res.send(500) };
    res.locals.foobar = 'hello world';     
    // res.locals.x is equivalent to passing {x:_} inline to render as below: 
    res.render('jade2', {user: result});
  });
});
```

Comment: You could also put the entire routing function in a separate file and require it from app.js, thus setting up your routes. I think this is the behavior in the default express setup, I also think it is demonstrated well [in the express examples](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/route-separation)

Comment: Also it's fine to just put logic directly in your routes. Some downsides are that it's less reusable if you want to call the function from somewhere else, and it clutters up your routes.

Comment: How would you integrate that with html generated by jade? for example the default index page from an express tool generated app.

Terrific answer by the way, thank you.

Comment: I personally just delete the index.js page and the references to it from app.js, and use my own file structure as I feel appropriate. If you want to use jade, you will call `res.render`, i will edit with two possible ways to do so